# How to filter by the elements of a Cartesian product of columns in R with dplyr?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a data.frame where

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),b = c(1,2,1,2,1,2), c = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

I want to keep the rows that match a key. For example,

```
key = data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c(1,2))
```

In this case I want remove rows not containing (a = 1 and b = 1) or ( a = 2 and b = 2). In general the values of the a and b pairs are not the same value and there could be more matching columns than just two. The important part is keeping only the rows that are in the key. The resulting data.frame should look like

```
df_result = data.frame(a = c(1,1,2,2), b = c(1,1,2,2), c = c(1,3,4,6))
```

I can only come up with an inelegant approach with loops and if functions and is not as generalized as I need (stated above).

```
nomatch = numeric(0)
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
   if((df$a[i] != key$a[1] | df$b[i] != key$b[1]) & (df$a[i] != key$a[2] | df$b[i] != key$b[2]))
       nomatch = c(nomatch,i)
}

df_result2 = df[-nomatch,]
```

I would prefer to be able to do this in dplyr.

Comment: @akrun, the proposed solution works for the posted example but does not generalize to the situation I previously described at the end "in general the values of the a and b pairs are not the same value and there could be more matching columns than just two". I reworded the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inner join of `df` and `key`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  inner_join(key)

#   a b c
# 1 1 1 1
# 2 1 1 3
# 3 2 2 4
# 4 2 2 6
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like df %>% semi_join(key) will also do the trick.

Comment: Yeah inner joins and semi-joins are the same unless your `y` table has multiple rows with the same values for all the columns by which you're joining. In that case an inner join returns multiple rows (due to multiple matches) while a semi-join only returns one.